# How do we know that a non recurring number will not repeat after many digits?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion

We are told that there are rational numbers that either terminate or repeat and irrationals that neither terminate nor repeat. But how are we so sure that a non terminating non recurring number will not repeat after, say $1000$th or $100000$th place? Has anybody calculated up to such large digits?

Comment: You are correct in thinking that just looking at the decimal will never prove that a number is irrational.  It might be suggestive, but it will never settle the point.  For that, other methods are needed.

Comment: Usually such proof involves showing that it's impossible to represent a number as a fraction with integer numerator and denominator. On the other hand, it's possible to show that repeated decimal can be written as such fraction.

Comment: What is the difference between non-recurring and non-repeating? (Also, it is easier to treat "terminating" decimals as "repeating" the digit $0.$)

Comment: There is no way to tell if a number is rational or not (and hence is repeating or not) by looking at its first $n$ digits. That's because the possible real values that start with those digits is a non-trivial interval $\left[r,r+1/10^n\right],$ and any non-trivial interval of the real numbers contains rationals and irrationals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First a simple observation; a terminating number is also a repeating number; it repeats the digit $0$ indefinitely. So we might as well say that rational numbers repeat, and irrational numbers do not.

You ask how we can be so sure that a non-repeating number will not repeat after many digits, say $100000$. This is easy; a non-repeating number does not repeat *by definition*.

If you would like to know how we can be so sure that an *irrational* number will not repeat after many digits; this is not as easy. Here's the idea: Suppose $x$ is a number that repeats at some point. Let's say that it repeats after $12$ digits, and then repeats in a loop of $50$ digits. Then the *decimal parts* of $10^{12}x$ and $10^{12+50}x$ are the same; they are both the same repeating loop of $50$ digits. This means that the decimal part of $10^{62}x-10^{12}x$ is $0$, so this is an integer, say $n$. Then a bit of algebra shows that
$$n=10^{62}x-10^{12}x=(10^{62}-10^{12})x,$$
which shows that $x=\frac{n}{10^{62}-10^{12}}$. In particular this means that $x$ is *rational*.

Of course this argument works for all other positive integers as well, not just $12$ and $50$. So this proves that every repeating number is rational. So every irrational number is non-repeating.

Comment: And the converse? That every rational has an eventually repeating decimal expansion?

Comment: @Lubin That's an interesting question too, though I hadn't interpreted the question as asking that. The only proof I know uses a bit of group theory, which doesn't seem appropriate here. Feel free to add your own answer though.

Comment: Can't it be done just by observing the remainders at each step in school style long division?  If you calculate $p / q$ then, at each step, the remainder will be in the range $0$ to $q - 1$.  If a $0$ occurs then it terminates (or repeats $0$ if you prefer).  Otherwise, it must repeat in $q - 1$ steps at most.